# What is a non-alternating simple group with big order, but relatively few conjugacy classes?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, characters

```
I'm not sure if this question is legal.
```

I'm writing my BsC thesis on character theoretical calculations and I have already calculated a lot of character tables (a few alternating, symmetric, $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$, etc..), but I still have some space, so I thought I could choose a group, with not too many conjugacy classes (around $7$ still fit in nicely), that is preferably not monomial.

What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you will be arrested shortly.

Comment: the StackExchange police are on their way already?

Comment: Anywho, you could try something fancy like a semidirect product (other than a dihedral group) or maybe even a Wreath product. Pick your poison. There's plenty of small groups to build'm from.

Comment: $A_5$, $A_6$ and ${\rm PSL}(2,7) \cong {\rm PSL}(3,2)$ are the only finite nonabelian simple groups with at most $7$ conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a big fan of the [group $\operatorname{PSL}(2,7)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSL(2,7)), also known as $\operatorname{GL}(3,2)$, which is finite, simple, not isomorphic to an alternating group, and has precisely $6$ conjugacy classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What makes you a fan of it?

Comment: @MátéKadlicskó The fact that it describes two seemingly different geometries, and that it is small enough to allow any calculations to be done manually.